Clang does not generate debug info for external symbols
I define some symbols in assembly source, assembling the source to elf format. Then I declare these symbols in C source so I can access them.
If I use clang with -g option to generate debug info for the binary, no debug info will be generated for these external symbols. But gcc will.
When I use GDB to debug the program compiled by clang, GDB complains that it doesn't know the types of the external symbols, so I have to cast these symbols to their declared types every time when I want to print their value.
Here is an example.
; test.asm
global array
section .data
array:
  dd 0
  dd 0
  dd 0

nasm test.asm -o test.asm~ -f elf64

extern int array[3];

int main()
{
  array[0] = 0;
  array[1] = 1;
  array[1] = 2;
}

clang test.asm~ test.c -o test -g

clang does not generate debug info for array, which means each time I want to print array[1], I have to cast it to declared type first.
Reading symbols from test...
(gdb) p array[1]
'array' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type

gcc test.asm~ test.c -o test -g

But gcc does, I can print type info of array.
Reading symbols from test...
(gdb) p array[1]
$1 = 2
(gdb) ptype array
type = int [3]
(gdb)

Is there any command line option available for clang to generate debug info for external symbols?
I've tried -gdescribe-dies, which is available in gcc, but it's not supported in clang.
